# What's the best way to deal with differences between JSON and Python when deserializing?

Tags: python, json, deserialization

I'm working with a messaging service using a python based API. The API does most of the deserializing work, rendering messages into python dictionaries. However, in some cases, the rendered dictionary includes a metadata key/value pair where the value is a string rendering of a dictionary that has not been deserialized. I've created a simple deserialize method, but I've had to amend it repeatedly to cover three differences between python and JSON, i.e. single vs double quotes, the case differences in boolean values, and None vs null:

```
def deserializeMetaData(metaDataStr):
    metaDataStr = metaDataStr.replace("'",'"').replace('True', 'true').replace('False', 'false').replace('None', 'null')
    metaDataDict = json.loads(metaDataStr)
    return metaDataDict

metaDataStr = "{'SomeCount': 1, 'SomeOtherCount': 2, 'SomeBool': True, 'SomethingElse': None}" 
deserializeMetaData(metaDataStr)
{'SomeCount': 1, 'SomeOtherCount': 2, 'SomeBool': True, 'SomethingElse': None}
```

It seems like really bad practice to target specific corner cases as I have with the repeated call to `replace`. Is there another way to approach this that would cover these and all corner cases better?

Comment: Why don't you just use a valid serializer?

Comment: @ScottHunter can you elaborate on that? Not sure what a valid deserializer would be.

Comment: One that produces valid JSON; like `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 0):

Might have been interpreting `metaDataStr` incorrectly as JSON that needs to be deserialized. Instead, looking at it as a string literal of a dictionary leads to the [Abstract Syntax Tree (ast) module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#literals).

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
> literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
> consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
> values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
> oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
> expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

So the following is enough to transform the string into a dictionary without issues:

```
import ast
    
metaDataStr = "{'SomeCount': 1, 'SomeOtherCount': 2, 'SomeBool': True, 'SomethingElse': None}"
d = ast.literal_eval(metaDataStr)
type(d)
Out[18]: dict
```